# Conditional rendering always false

Tags: reactjs, rendering, conditional-statements

I have a component that responsible for displaying a Category List.
In it I have declare a const called "thereAreCategories", that should be true when there are any categories passed from Categories component. 
for now, it is false all the time and shows the "Please add a new category" paragraph.

```
render() {
        const { categories } = this.props;
        const thereAreCategories = categories.length > 0
        return (

            <div className="category-list">
                {
                    thereAreCategories ?

                            <ul>
                                {categories.map(category =>
                                    < li
                                        key={category.id}
                                        onClick={() => this.toggle(category.id)}
                                        style={!category.isToggled ?
                                            { borderColor: '' } : { border: '2px solid red' }}>
                                        {category.term}
                                    </li>)}
                            </ul>

                        :

                            <p>Plese add a new category</p>

                }

                <button onClick={this.logProps}>Props</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

The state is living in the Categories component.

Comment: are you sure categories  is not provided properly as a prop

Comment: Yes I am sure, I think that the render method is the problem here but I can't figure it out.

Comment: try printing categories and also make sure that if catergories is an immutable List, you use `size` instead of  `length`

Comment: Found the problem, nothing that refers to rendering. ty